# Server trying to connect to Spamhaus DROP networks

Tags: attacks, forensics, spamhaus

I have a small Ubuntu mail/web server running an outbound proxy server and also recently using the [Spamhaus DROP](https://www.spamhaus.org/blocklists/do-not-route-or-peer) lists to block connections from and to the networks listed in those.

I see almost as many outbound connections being dropped to those networks from our postfix mail server on port 25 as I do inbound (typically on SASL ports).

Sometimes an offending IP tries to connect to smtp (multiple times), then about an hour or so later postfix tries to connect back to it. For example at 00:07:10 before the DROP rules were implemented and then 09:47:46 after:

```
Mar 09 00:07:10 postfix/smtpd[1421282]: connect from unknown[87.120.84.205]
Mar 09 00:07:11 postfix/smtpd[1421282]: disconnect from unknown[87.120.84.205] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
...
Mar 09 09:47:46 kernel: [SPAMHAUS BLOCK]IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=[MYSERVER] DST=87.120.84.205 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=25 DPT=51767 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 ECE ACK SYN URGP=0 
Mar 09 09:47:47 kernel: [SPAMHAUS BLOCK]IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=[MYSERVER] DST=87.120.84.205 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=25 DPT=51767 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 ECE ACK SYN URGP=0
```

The blocks occur perhaps every 5 to 10 seconds, stopping for perhaps a few minutes then starting again.

This feels like it warrants more investigation, but I'm not sure where to start. The mail logs don't show failed attempts to make connections over port 25. I also see the firewall dropping attempts to connect out on 443 to these networks sometimes too.